# Is reverse proxy in ServiceFabric configurable?

Tags: service-fabric-on-premises

We have on-premise 3-nodes cluster for devs in our office: 6.1.467, WinSrv2016. Everything works fine. Now we need to configure built-in service fabric reverse proxy (port 19081). For example, increase proxy timeout (now it is 120s) or enable client affinity. But I cannot find any information about how to do it.

Can anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a configuration for client affinity.

I suggest you use dedicated load balancer for it. You can use naming service to query the address of your service and manage affinity at load balancer level.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I will take your advice. Do you have any thoughts about my second problem - proxy timeout?